# В каких языках точка с запятой отделяет комментарий?

Tags: любой-язык, синтаксис, комментарии

В каких языках точка с запятой отделяет комментарий?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то согласно [этой ссылке](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Comments)

> AutoHotkey, AutoIt, Lisp, Common Lisp, Clojure, Rebol, Scheme, many
>   assemblers

Comment: Ещё в `INI file`, но это не язык.

Answer (score -1):

В ubuntu подсветить комментарии после ";" можно в редакторе nano
стандартная цветовая схема elisp (это диалект языка Lisp)

> nano -Y elisp /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

В винде в редакторе Notepad++ в меню выбрать: Синтаксис -> L -> LISP

Comment: а какое отношение к вопросу имеет то, что вы написали?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).